# Two missing user boxes on Election overview

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, election

The [Election page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election) shows an overview of all elections held for this stack, now that there's currently no election in progress.
The overview looks a bit off with two missing userboxes, since two former mods left this stack entirely.

[image: A screenshot of the election overview page, with two missing userboxes]

Comment: [meta-tag:status-bydesign], I suspect. Deleted users' usernames don't show up anywhere as far as I know.

Comment: I agree, but that's the point of account deletion: *nothing* of the user is left visible, not even the name(s) they used to have. In the same way as nobody would know user8719 was called Jimmy Shelter, Darth Satan, Darth Melkor if we didn't all know him by reputation.

Comment: I do think it is a bug. It should say something to the effect that someone whose account no longer exists was elected, not show broken-image icons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### This has now been fixed.

The departed mods' names still don't show up, but the two tiny "missing user" icons have been enlarged to show that three moderators *were* elected in 2012 even though two have now left the site:

[image]

This seems to be the best solution that balances these users' desire for privacy with the natural wish to see them recognised as former moderators of this community.

Comment: I wonder if "Departed" is the best caption; it reads a bit like "deceased". How about "User Left"? Other than that, good solution.

Comment: It made me instantly think of "*dearly departed*". +1 to the idea of having something clearer such as "user has requested removal"

Comment: I’ll third SQB and @Richard’s point. _Departed_ sounds a tad over-dramatic. I would suggest “Deleted user” or “Deleted profile” instead, which is neutral and accurate. After all, it is not necessarily the case that a deleted account is the result of the user requesting removal or leaving—there are forced deletions as well (though I’ll admit I’ve never heard of a former mod being actually deleted—that’s usually limited to spammers and fake accounts).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I can imagine no circumstances where a mod would be *deleted*. They're almost by definition high-rep users who will have contributed extensively. Even if SE don't want to keep the person, they'll certainly want to keep their content.

Comment: @Richard I may be conflating two types of account deletion here. Have Gilles’ and Keen’s accounts been completely deleted, so that all their answers and history are gone completely? Or have they just been ‘numerised’ like user8719? Or rather, is it only the former type of deletion that would trigger the “Departed” (or whatever) placeholder on the Election page? I had just assumed that both types of deletion would have that effect, and I do believe there are precedents to high-rep users being ‘numerised’ (not by their own request).

Comment: "Have Gilles’ and Keen’s accounts been completely deleted, so that all their answers and history are gone completely?" This never happens, @JanusBahsJacquet; the content you've posted to the site [is licensed to SE for use in perpetuity](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) (section "Subscriber Content"). You can ask that your account be deleted, but the content remains.

Comment: @Richard Pedantry compels me to point out that this isn't always the case, especially with pro-tem mods. I've seen mods with rep in the low hundreds and hardly any posts. But your point does stand: a user who's been a mod at any time is unlikely to be deleted against their will.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Like Josh says, only their *accounts* are deleted (meaning any info about them as users); the content they've posted remains. As for what 'triggers' the *Departed* placeholder: I'd have to ask a CM, but I suspect that was custom-made; the only placeholder generated by the system was the tiny little thing shown in SQB's question.

Comment: Then I’m back to my initial point: although it’s quite unlikely, it _could happen_ that a mod (or, perhaps more likely, a former mod) somehow warranted having his or her account deleted, for whatever reason. That’s the reason I figured it would be better to have a wording that doesn’t explicit state that the deletion of the user account was of their own choosing—having a neutral one that simply says the user account was deleted works equally well in either scenario.